# Initing certain values in too many of an object makes my app crash

Tags: objective-c, ios, singleton

I'm filling in a singleton object with mock data to spit out in a function that returns the array that all of this data goes into.

```
@interface menuItem : NSObject {
//Item's Name
NSString *itemName;
//String of Prices - "$4.50" or "$1.50 / $2.50 / $3.50"
NSArray *priceList;
//List of Ingredients 
NSArray *ingredientList;
//List of adjusted Quantities
NSArray *ingredientQuants; 
//Number of Sizes for corresponding prices
int numOfSizes;
}
- (NSString *)priceText;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *itemName;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *priceList;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *ingredientList;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *ingredientQuants;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int numOfSizes;
@end
```

The object doesn't care how many objects I put in it with menuItems with values stored in ingredientQuants, but after a number of declarations, it gets sick of letting ones that do have ingredientQuants declared, even with variables that are declared right before I stash them there, and then it decides to EXEC_BAD_ACCESS on main.c

```
-(NSArray *)returnAllItems {
  return items;
}

- (void) loadMenu { 
   if(categories && items){ 
     return;
}
categories = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Coffee", @"Coffee Alternatives", @"Smoothies", @"Baked Goods", @"Sandwiches",@"Salads", nil];

NSArray *nyQuants = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"No", @"Yes", nil];
//NSArray *ynQuants = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Yes", @"No", nil];
NSArray *numQuants = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", @"6", @"7", @"8", @"0", nil];
NSArray *espressoIList = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Decaf", @"Iced", @"Soymilk", @"Shots",nil];

menuItem *menuitemOne = [[menuItem alloc] init];
menuitemOne.itemName = @"Regular Coffee";
menuitemOne.priceList = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"$1.50",@"$1.95",@"$2.15", nil];
menuitemOne.numOfSizes = 3;
// menuitemOne.ingredientList = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Decaf", @"Iced", nil];
//menuitemOne.ingredientQuants = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nyQuants, nyQuants, nil];

menuItem *menuItemTwo = [[menuItem alloc] init];
menuItemTwo.itemName = @"Latte";
menuItemTwo.priceList = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"$2.55", @"$3.45", @"$3.75", nil];
menuItemTwo.numOfSizes = 3;
menuItemTwo.ingredientList = espressoIList;
menuItemTwo.ingredientQuants = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nyQuants, nyQuants, nyQuants, numQuants, nil];

menuItem *mocha = [[menuItem alloc]init];
mocha.itemName = @"Mocha";
mocha.priceList = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"$3.15",@"$3.95",@"$4.75", nil];
mocha.numOfSizes = 3;
mocha.ingredientList = espressoIList;    
//THIS LINE BREAKS THE ENTIRE PROGRAM
NSArray *aaaa = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ASD", @"DFG", nil];
mocha.ingredientQuants = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:aaaa, nil];
```

//MORE STUFF HAPPENS LIKE ABOVE

```
items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:coffeeArray, espressoArray,smoothieArray, bakedArray, sandwichArray,saladArray, nil];

[nyQuants release];
[numQuants release];
[espressoIList release];

NSLog(@"Categories: %d", [categories retainCount]);
NSLog(@"items: %d", [items retainCount]);
NSLog(@"nyQuants: %d", [nyQuants retainCount]);
NSLog(@"numQuants: %d", [numQuants retainCount]);
NSLog(@"espresslist: %d", [espressoIList retainCount]);

}
```

Then I init this object, grab its member arrays and put them in a viewcontroller:

```
        CBMenu *WholeMenu = [CBMenu sharedInstance];
    NSLog(@"MENU");
    NSArray *cats = [WholeMenu returnCategories];
    NSLog(@"Cats");
    NSArray *menu = [WholeMenu returnAllItems];
    NSLog(@"Menu");

    //What are these I don't even
    [cats retain];
    [menu retain];

    FoodMenuTwoViewController *mmvc = [[FoodMenuTwoViewController alloc]initWithData:cats :NO: YES];
    [mmvc setDataSource:cats];
    [mmvc setMenu:menu];
    [mmvc setTitle:@"Menu"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:mmvc animated:YES];

    //FOR SOME REASON IT DOESN'T LIKE ME RELEASING CATS AND MENU OR REMOVING THEIR
    //RETAIN STATEMENTS ABOVE PLEASE DON'T HURT ME.

    return;
```

When the first bool in the VC is YES, it shows a list of categories. I see this, but when the view appears when it's pushed onto the stack, it proceeds to vomit all of its organs up and die.

NSZombieEnabled tells me CharlieBrown[4285:fb03] *** -[__NSArrayI retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6e06550

Comment: Do you have the NSZombieEnabled environment set to YES?

Comment: Yeah, I keep getting [21673:fb03] *** -[__NSArrayI release]: message sent to deallocated instance blahblah or [__NSArrayI retain], depending on if I remove the unused variable ynquants specified above

Comment: Pleas give us the EXEC BAD ACCESS error message

Comment: retainCount is useless.  Don't call it.

Answer (score 1):

Set the properties of NSStrings and NSArrays to copy instead of retain and in your init method dont use [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:] on your Ingredients List and espressoIList- you dont do it with the other arrays (which is correct). Otherwise you get memory leaks. Use NSArray arrayWithObjects like you did with most of the other arrays.

Edit:

Also change this

```
menuItemTwo.ingredientList = espressoIList;
```

To

```
menuItemTwo.ingredientList = [NSArray arrayWithArray: espressoIList ];
```

Edit:

Since you say it didn't help you making these adjustments, maybe post the code
you indicate with //more lik this

I don't really see why you get the problem yet. Which is the line causing the crash? 
this one?

```
mocha.ingredientQuants = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nyQuants, nil];
```

And if you leave it out it just works?

Edit:

It seems to me nyQuants was released when you tried to add it to the mocha array.
Seems the autoreleasepool gets drained and the object vanishes - though i thought that would only happen after the run loop.
Try to nitialize your nyQuants and other arrays you depend on using alloc init and release them manually after your declaration of all menuItems is done.
I think that should do it!

So, change those

```
NSArray *nyQuants = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"No", @"Yes", nil];
NSArray *ynQuants = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Yes", @"No", nil];
NSArray *numQuants = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", @"6",     @"7", @"8", @"0", nil];
NSArray *espressoIList = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Decaf", @"Iced", @"Soymilk", @"Shots",nil];
```

All to be alloced like espressoIList is in this example and release them when before your method returns.

Comment: How can I use arrayWithArray on arrays that I'm making out of other non-arrayed objects?

Comment: Alternately: How can I be sure that it's even a memory leaking problem: The program EXEC_BAD_ACCESSes when I load the view that utilizes the category and item arrays being init'd

Comment: Sorry, I meant use arrayWithObjects, not arrayWithArray

Comment: It's a memory management problem if your zombie tells us NSArrayI release]: message sent to deallocated instance. Give the original bad access erro message please.

Comment: I'm getting *** -[__NSArrayI retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x8862280

And zombie nukes the thing on main.c and just has the line-arrow read "Thread 1", so...

Comment: I have, no dice:
-Changing properties to copy
-Changing array declarations to arrayWithObjects instead of alloc-init

Comment: That's an adjustment I've tried.

I've tried making different items have both the old arrays, or new arrays spawned just before use. All to no avail. The only way I can not have the program crash or hang is to limit the number of menuItem objects I'm stashing that have ingredientQuants with values in them.

It's like the laws of everything don't apply :|

Comment: Enacting those changes makes my code a bit more consistent, but it hasn't really done much else. 

Edited into the OP is more info about the flow of the items array, since it's either that, or something living inside it that's killing itself due to the fact that I'm seeing a list from the "categories" array before it dies.

Comment: I also have the CBMenu that these things live in as a sharedInstance, and there is no dealloc, but I'm not sure if that's wrong or not :|

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a NSArray - message sent to deallocated instance, means that you are using a variable with a negative retain count, you deleted/released it somehow.

In the header file you declared your arrays with `(nonatomic, retain)`, it means that their retain count is 1. In the m file you should deallocate the arrays in the `- (void)dealloc{}` method. You initialized your arrays with arrayWithObjects method, and based on the [apple memory management](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html) description, with this method you don't own these object, so you cannot release/delete/remove them.

Comment: First part is right - he has to release them. Second part is wrong, since he is using the propertie's setter method, the array gets retained - and therefore has to be released. Though it shoul better be "copied".

Comment: So, then, should I check and see which of my objects I'm prematurely releasing? How would I know which one to look for? :|

Comment: try to add a NSLog(@"%d", [object retaincount]); to your code to see where is the problem exactly

Comment: What benefits do I actually get changing the property to (nonatomic, copy)? 

It's not really doing much for me here @__@

Comment: BTW, why did you use two different initializing methods when you created nyQuants and espressoIList arrays?

Comment: I made them both at entirely different times: One before the beer, the other one after.

Comment: Even when I declare objects to be stashed in menuItems right before I put them into them, it cries and dies. This is gonna be a long night.

Comment: In these cases, when I cannot locate with which array is the problem, I put some NSLogs in the code, even after each array creation. If the array was created successfully, the log is printed in the screen.